# Multiple users XDebug and PHP Debugging

Tags: php, xdebug

How do you setup a multi-developer XDebug PHP environment?

I have the following setup:

- I have a linux machine with Apache and Xdebug loaded and a php.ini file that I think is correct.
- I found a python proxy script that I'm using to proxy the calls from the PDT Eclipse IDE's my developers are using to the Apache/Xdebug running on the same web server.
- I set the idekey in php.ini to "ECLIPSE_DBGP" and for Xdebug to autostart

From the log information from the proxy it says that there is no server with the key "ECLIPSE_DBGP" and it stops the request.

**Has anybody run into this or has a step by step setup to get this to work?**

I have exhausted what I have found using google.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use ssh to tunnel the debug-connection back to your client machine. Eg. from your client machine, connect to the server with something like:

```
ssh -R 9000:localhost:9000 you@example.com
```

Then fire up your (local) debugger, and start the remote script. Xdebug (at the server) will now establish a connection to its `localhost:9000`, but since this port is forwarded back to your local machine, your (local) debugger will receive the connection.

If you use Windows on your client side, you can do the same thing with PuTTY.

[See the documentation for Spectator](http://code.google.com/p/spectator/w/list) for some more details.

Comment: not actually addressing the question, but what I was looking for nonetheless. Spectator still works, after 2 years of bitrot :)

Comment: @eric Yeah, there are some minor bugs and things that could be nicer about spectator, but I haven't had the time to do anything about them.

Comment: If we are remote debugging, would the xdebug.remotehost line in the php.ini be set to localhost? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818202/remote-php-debugging-with-netbeans-and-xdebug?rq=1

Comment: @cymbals - Yes, the ssh command routes the (remote) localhost back to your debugger client. So from Xdebug's perspective, it talks to localhost.

Comment: @troelskn - Thanks! Would this would be limited to one person debugging at a time, since everyone would be using the same port?

Comment: @cymbals - Yes, you could only connect one at a time. But I suppose you could start multiple debug connections on different ports (Change the `xdebug.remote_port` setting on a per-site basis) and then each user could ssh in and forward that port back to their local 9000. Is it a real issue though? Can't you just take turns to use the debugger?