# Remote PHP Debugging with Netbeans and XDebug

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, xdebug, remote-debugging

I'm trying to use XDebug in the following scenario

- Physical Host on Windows 7, with Netbeans 7.1.1
- Virtual guest on Ubuntu, with Apache server and PHP 5.3.10
- the PHP code of my website is on a shared folder on Ubuntu, in /var/www/mysite
- the PHP code is accessible from my Windows host, on \\guestIP\mysite, with R/W permissions
- Website accessible from http://mysite.local.fr, from both host and guest

I created a Netbeans project from my Windows Host, pointing to \\guestIP\mysite.
In the project Run configuration, I have the following:

- Run as: Local web server
- Project URL: http://mysite.local.fr
- Index file: index.php (does exist in the project)

In the Advanced Run Configuration:

- I checked "Ask every time" (I also tried using "Do not ask" and starting the browser with the session key  myself)
- I tried setting '/var/www/mysite' - \\GuestIP\mysite for the mapping (and tried using nothing as well)
- I haven't touched the proxy settings

I have the following in the php.ini on my Ubuntu VM

```
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /tmp
;xdebug.remote_host=localhost,<HostIP>, mysite.local.fr
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_mode=req
```

None of this works, Netbeans does not stop at any breakpoint from Windows.

**Debugging directly from my VM with Netbeans works fine.**

Can someone tell me how to get my debugger to work remotely from Windows?
Thanks

Comment: You ever figure this out?  I have almost the exact same configuration and I can't get a breakpoint to fire either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sorry, i can't comment anymore.  @David @JamesB41: I've been looking for this too.  My setup is a Windows 7 host with NetBeans 7.1, and an Ubuntu VM in VirtualBox.  I have the NetBeans project set up as a remote project, uploading and downloading using SFTP.

The following setup works for me, just use your host's IP as remote_host, and make sure the VM can see it.

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=10.217.165.193
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/log/xdebug.log"
```

NetBeans will stop at the entry point breakpoint (if you have the option set in PHP->Debugging).  <strike>But, it won't stop on NetBeans-created breakpoints, because its running off the VM's files.  You can use xdebug_break() though, and it will show stack and variables.</strike>  It will stop at NetBeans breakpoints and highlight if you map the folders correctly in project config > Run Config > Advanced.  Awesome.  I am complete.

(The `connect_back` config didn't seem to help, possibly because $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] isn't populated.)

Answer (score 3):

Go through the below document for remote debugging using NetBeans. Very helpful.
http://stuporglue.org/setting-up-xdebug-with-netbeans-on-windows-with-a-remote-apache-server/

Answer (score 1):

In know this is old but a good reminder. Make sure if you are using nat in virtualbox that you set port forwarding on the xdebug port back to the local machine typically 9000 by default.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to have the VM configured to speak to its own localhost:9000 (default for xdebug) and then ssh in from host to VM and establish a port tunnel for that port back to the host machine. Then your host machine debugger simply connects to localhost:9000 and everything should work exactly as if they were running on the same machine.

See: [Multiple users XDebug and PHP Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184365/multiple-users-xdebug-and-php-debugging/184802?noredirect=1#comment24915552_184802)

Answer (score 0):

### Debugging remotely with Linux + Apache + PHP + xdebug + NetBeans (SFTP)

I've got the following setup and it works.

**Host PC (client)**

- Linux Debian Jessie **
- NetBeans version 8.0.2
- NetBeans has a project created as "PHP Application from Remote
  Server", that has to be debugged
- NetBeans connects to Remote Server using SFTP
- IP (for example): 192.168.0.2

** I am aware that the OP question mentions Windows, but regarding that the main setup to solve this should be made on the VM, I hope this helps somebody anyway.

**Guest PC (server) / Virtual Machine**

- Linux Debian Jessie
- Apache
- PHP 5.6
- xdebug 2.2.5
- IP (for example): 192.168.0.1

**The following steps should be made on the "Guest PC (server) / Virtual Machine"**

1. install xdebug `sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug`
2. edit `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`,

add these lines right before the `[Date]` AND change `xdebug.remote_host` to reflect your "Host PC (client)" IP:

```
[debug]
; Remote settings
xdebug.remote_autostart=off
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.0.2
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

3. restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart`

**Reference**

How to configure XDebug - Remote Debuging http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug#Remote_Debuging

> you need to have correctly configured property xdebug_remote.host on
>   remote machine. The IP address of local machine has to be defined in
>   this property. For example, you want to debug your source code on
>   remote machine 192.168.0.1 using Netbeans installed on 192.168.0.2.
>   You need to change xdebug.remote_host on 192.168.0.1 to
>   xdebug.remote_host=192.168.0.2. If doesn't work verify you have port
>   configured in xdebug.remote_port open on both machines.

Comment: Sometimes I just really want to say - WHAT THE F**K. I have do this multiple times in the past and this time it just does not work. Changed xdebug.remote_host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to host IP address and it magically started to work!

Answer (score 0):

If all seems to be correct but you still get "Waiting For Connection" from inside netbeans you should try in your php.ini settings

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back=on
```

as it allows connection from ANY ip or look at a lot more info on the issue http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/netbeans-waiting-for-connection-netbeans-xdebug-issue