# Netbeans xdebug (remote): entry file not in project scope

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

i have a problem regarding netbeans in combination with xdebug *on a remote machine*.

### Installation

My php.ini looks like this one(accepted answer)
[Remote PHP Debugging with Netbeans and XDebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818202/remote-php-debugging-with-netbeans-and-xdebug)

And everything works pretty normal. Simple projects I can debug on on the remote-server 9000. I also can use the debug-button on netbeans.

### The problem

As long as the the entry file is inside the project everything works fine. The problem starts when the file is *outside the project scope*. Imagine a project called Calculator. But the files get never called directly, they get included by an index-file outside the current project.

**So the project(in netbeans) looks like this**

- Calculator

  - file1.php
  - file2.php

**The real file structure looks like this as an example**

- index.php

  - Calculator

    - file1.php
    - file2.php

### Solution?

The index.php gets called via debugger. The debug waits somewhere in that index.php (I can see this at the "call stack") if I checked "stop on start" in the project properties. Even if the index-file includes file1.php I cannot get to a breakpoint. It runs through till the end. breakpoints are ignored.

A solution was to put the project at the root-level(including the index.php) but this is in that case not acceptable. 
Has anyone an idea what I could do to get this working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I know, this is a limitation in Netbeans which refuses to do anything if the files are not in the project scope. I would suggest you file a bug with them.

Comment: Ok. I immediately stopped working on netbeans and configured the same scenario in eclipse. Eclipse does not have a problem configuring path params(server to workspace) and everything works fine. If there is also a solution for netbeans, please let me know. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but you always can extend NetBeans outside of project definitions. 
Go to Project->Properties->Include Path and add your external directories. They should resolve not only in xdebug but any Namespaces & classes etc. Can be read by code complete.